# GRUB (error no such device)

Tags: boot, grub2

Summary:
1. Installed a fresh Ubuntu Server 14.04
2. I have installed it on the first HDD 320GB and the second is free(also 320gb)
3. Tried also boot repair, but nothing happend, getting the same error
4. Details from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12894358/
Question:
1. I don't know what else I can do? Anyone of you know how to fix this.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Why is drive seen as sdf? Is this an external drive? If so may be better to have smaller / (root) and large /home or data partition, or a /boot partition. Some BIOS have issue booting from beyond a certain point with USB drives, similar to the now very old BIOS boot issue with very large drives. (When very large was over 120GB).

Comment: Ok, will try to reinstall ubuntu. No its no external drive.

Comment: I've reinstall ubuntu and I've got the same error. My pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/12895524/

Comment: Are you getting grub> or grub rescue>? Have you tried pressing enter after error? Do you get grub menu. With one install you have to press & hold shift key from BIOS until menu appears.  With nVidia you need to add nomodeset also anyway, but have to get past no such device error first. I have add similar issues with installs to flash drives that were sdg or f, while grub uses UUID, it seems to stop looking if no drives sda, sdb, sdc etc. If only drive still do not understand why sde or sdf? Do you have a multi-card reader plugged in and it is sda thru sdd?

Comment: I didn't tried to press enter after that. I'm getting grub rescue. So I'm a little bit confused. The first time I installed it, everything was fine. Then I screwed up with some settings and I need a fresh install. After that I cannot get ubuntu to work.